# How to derive the commutation relationship between $\hat{L}^2$ and $\hat{\textbf{p}}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, vectors, commutator

How to prove that

$$[\hat{L}^2,\hat{\textbf{p}}] = i\hbar(\hat{\textbf{p}}\times\hat{\textbf{L}} - \hat{\textbf{L}} \times \hat{\textbf{p}})$$

I tried to expand  $\hat{L}^2$:

$$[\hat{L}^2,\hat{\textbf{p}}] = [\hat{L}^2_x+\hat{L}^2_y+\hat{L}^2_z,\hat{\textbf{p}}]$$

And

\begin{align*}
    [\hat{L}^2_x,\hat{\textbf{p}}] &= [\hat{L}_x\hat{L}_x,\hat{\textbf{p}}] \\
                                   &= \hat{L}_x[\hat{L}_x,\hat{\textbf{p}}] + [\hat{L}_x,\hat{\textbf{p}}]\hat{L}_x \\
\end{align*}

With $[\hat{L}_x,\hat{p}_y]=[\hat{p}_x,\hat{L}_y]=i\hbar \hat{p}_z$
 and $[\hat{L}_x,\hat{p}_x]=0$,

$$
    [\hat{L}_x,\hat{\textbf{p}}] = i\hbar(\hat{p}_z\vec{e}_y-\hat{p}_y\vec{e}_z)
$$

So the LHS of the equation in the question is simply $\textbf{0}$, which is wrong. Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing for this exercise is to use Levi-Civita symbol for the vector product: $$\vec{a} \times \vec{b} = a_i b_j e_k \varepsilon_{ijk},$$
where I denote by $e_i$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Using this notation, we have:
$$[L_j,p_i]=[r_k p_l \varepsilon_{klj},p_i]= i \hbar p_l \varepsilon_{ilj}.$$
and 
$$[L^2,\vec{p}]=e_i[L_j L_j,p_i]=e_i([L_j,p_i]L_j +L_j[L_j,p_i])=i\hbar (\vec{p}\times\vec{L}-\vec{L}\times\vec{p}).$$

Be careful to use correctly the anti-symmetry of the Levi-Civita symbol in the last step.